# OWIN not working on live server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, owin

I am using OWIN to implement OAUTH2 in my MVC WEB API application.
I have setup the startup like this

```
public static OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthOptions { get; private set; }

static Startup()
{
    OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
    {
        TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),           
        Provider = new CustomOAuthProvider(),
        RefreshTokenProvider = new CustomOAuthRefreshProvider(),
        AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(180),
        AllowInsecureHttp = true
    };
}

public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);
}
```

The CustomOAuthProvider Class contains

```
public override Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
{
    return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        var username = context.UserName;
        var password = context.Password;
        var userService = new Merchants();
        MerchantsModel user = userService.Authenticate(username, password);
        if (user.MerchantId > 0)
        {
            var claims = new List<Claim>()
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.MerchantName),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, user.EmailId),
                new Claim("CompanyName", user.CompanyName),
                new Claim("UserID", user.MerchantId.ToString()),
                new Claim("CreatedOn", DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"))
            };

            ClaimsIdentity oAutIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, Startup.OAuthOptions.AuthenticationType);

            context.Validated(new AuthenticationTicket(oAutIdentity, new AuthenticationProperties() { }));
        }
        else
        {
            context.SetError("Invalid Username or Password", "Error");
        }
    });
}
```

Now when i test this using POSTMAN it works perfectly on my local server and generates the access_token.
But when i deploy it on the web server it returns the error

```
{
  "error": "unsupported_grant_type"
}
```

Am i missing something here?
this is the first time i am implementing OAUTH2 in my application.
Do i need to add some more code of config to make it work on the live server.

P.S. The request i send for authenticating is same in both cases:

```
grant_type=password&username=myusername&password=mypassword
```

Comment: are you using `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` as your content-type on the request?

Comment: I have solved the error today.

Comment: That's good. Please share your solution, as it may help others who face the same issue.

Comment: Turns out i was deploying the application on a virtual directory on the server. When i shifted the application to the root directory of the domain it started working. I dint change anything in the code and the request type was also same. The application was not receiving any parameters on virtual directory but same app received the data when deployed at root directory. Thanks for your help though. :)